# Radius of curvature of $r=2 \cdot e^{3 \phi}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have to find the curvature of $r=2 \cdot e^{3 \phi}$

$\dfrac{\left[1+\left(\dfrac{d y}{d x}\right)^2\right]^{\frac 3 2}}{\dfrac{d^2 y}{d x^2}}$

$x=r\cdot cos(\phi)=2 \cdot e^{3 \phi}\cdot cos(\phi)$

$y=r\cdot sin(\phi)=2 \cdot e^{3 \phi}\cdot sin(\phi)$

$\dfrac{d x}{d \phi}=-2 e^{3 \phi}\cdot (sin(\phi) - 3 cos(\phi))$

$\dfrac{d y}{d \phi}=2 e^{3 \phi}\cdot (3 sin(\phi) + cos(\phi))$

$\dfrac{d y}{d x}=\dfrac{2 e^{3 \phi}\cdot (3 sin(\phi) + cos(\phi))}{-2 e^{3 \phi}\cdot (sin(\phi) - 3 cos(\phi))}
=\dfrac{-3 sin(\phi) - cos(\phi)}{sin(\phi) - 3 cos(\phi)}$

$\dfrac{d^2 y}{d \phi^2}=4 e^{3 \phi}\cdot (4 sin(\phi) + 3 cos(\phi))$

$\dfrac{d^2 y}{d ^2 x}=\dfrac{\dfrac{2 e^{3 \phi}\cdot (4 sin(\phi) - 3 cos(\phi))}{50}}{\dfrac{2 e^{3 \phi}\cdot (sin(\phi) + 3 cos(\phi))}{10}}=\dfrac{4 sin(\phi) - 3 cos(\phi)}{5\cdot (sin(\phi) + 3 cos(\phi))}$

now using the radius of curvature formula i find an incredibly complex formula:

$\rho=\dfrac{\left[1+\left(\dfrac{d y}{d x}\right)^2\right]^{\frac 3 2}}{\dfrac{d^2 y}{d x^2}}=\dfrac{\left[1+\left(\dfrac{3 sin(\phi) - cos(\phi)}{sin(\phi) + 3 cos(\phi)}\right)^2\right]^{\frac 3 2}}{\dfrac{4 sin(\phi) - 3 cos(\phi)}{5\cdot (sin(\phi) + 3 cos(\phi))}}$

I can't find a way to write this in a more human way.

Comment: Have you tried using formula for [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_a_graph)?

Comment: Anyway there's a mistake you've done $\frac{dcos\phi}{d\phi}$ =-$ sin\phi$ whereas you've written it as + $sin\phi$ and same sign problem with $dsin\phi/d\phi$

Comment: oh sorry i see my mistake here i used integrals in stead of derivatives

Comment: You can simplify your expression by taking things to the common fraction and cancelling the denominators and more. Additionally, you lost the exponential parts somehow, when you calculated the last expression.
For better way, look at the answers about the polar coordinate calculation.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use the formula for curvature in terms of the function $r(\theta)$:

> If a curve is defined in polar coordinates as $r(\theta)$, then its curvature is
>   $$
>     \kappa(\theta)
>   = \frac{|r^2 + 2r'^2 - rr''|}{(r^2 + r'^2)^{3/2}}
> $$
>   where here the prime refers to the differentiation with respect to $\theta$.

The result is $e^{-3\theta}/(2\sqrt{10})$.

Comment: we can't use that formula on our exam

Comment: Please accept my deepest condolences.

Comment: Then show me where my mistake is please!

Comment: I cannot show you your mistake because you deleted it.

Comment: Yes since someone gave me a $-1$ i have checked it with WA!

Answer (score 0):

The curve $\gamma$ in question is a [logarithmic spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral). From the selfsimilarity properties of these spirals it immediately follows that $\rho(\phi)=c r(\phi)$ for some constant $c$. The following (human) computations will confirm this fact.

I shall use the parametric representation
$$\gamma:\quad\phi\mapsto{\bf z}(\phi):=2e^{3\phi}(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)\ .$$One computes
$$\eqalign{{\bf z}'(\phi)&=2e^{3\phi}(-\sin\phi+3\cos\phi, \cos\phi+3\sin\phi)\cr   &=2\sqrt{10}e^{3\phi}\bigl(\cos(\phi+\alpha),\sin(\phi+\alpha)\bigr)\ ,\cr}$$
whereby $\alpha:=\arctan{1\over3}$. It follows that the arc length $\phi\mapsto s(\phi)$ along $\gamma$ satisfies
$$s'(\phi)=\bigl|{\bf z}'(\phi)\bigr|=2\sqrt{10}e^{3\phi}\ ,$$ whereas the forward tangent direction is given by
$$\theta(\phi)=\arg\bigl({\bf z}'(\phi)\bigr)=\phi+\alpha\ .$$
Now the curvature $\kappa$ is the turning speed of the tangent with respect to arc length, hence
$$\kappa(\phi)={d\theta\over ds}={\theta'(\phi)\over s'(\phi)}={1\over2\sqrt{10}}e^{-3\phi}\ ,$$
so that we finally obtain
$$\rho(\phi)={1\over\kappa(\phi)}=2\sqrt{10}e^{3\phi}\ .$$